# Can't delete a btrfs snapshot

Tags: snapshot, btrfs

I have a system that creates periodic btrfs snapshots and deletes old ones. Today, I've started receiving warnings that the system can't delete some old snapshots.

This is the output I get:

```
root@machine:/path# btrfs sub del 2014-10-26--01-50-01-@ten_minutely
Delete subvolume '/path/2014-10-26--01-50-01-@ten_minutely'
ERROR: cannot delete '/path/2014-10-26--01-50-01-@ten_minutely'
```

I can create and delete new snapshots without a problem - just a couple of them, created today, exhibit this behaviour.

The permissions look ok.
Syslog show nothing related. 
I checked `btrfs filesystem df`, and there's space available for the filesystem - both for metadata and data.

A strace of the delete command shows:

```
#...
ioctl(3, 0x5000940f, 0xffa1d1f0)        = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
close(3)                                = 0
#...
```

What further steps can I take to investigate the cause?

Comment: I hope that you are not housing production data on a btrfs filesystem its not to that level yet.

Comment: @mdpc Sort of - it's a small system with just a couple of users. I've been using btrfs without significant problems for about 3 years now

Answer (score 4):

After some digging around, I found the root of the problem

**Inside the snapshots that cannot be deleted, there was a subvolume** - apparently another snapshot.
The system that creates periodic snapshots must have run twice for the same path - thus creating the second snapshot *inside* the first, instead of taking that name.

For the record, I'm using [btrfs-snapshot-rotation](https://github.com/mmehnert/btrfs-snapshot-rotation) through plain cron. Since I had multiple snapshot frequencies, two must have run in the same second. A potential solution is to switch to `anacron`.